# Depending selects in symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have two selects, where the user chooses the first product to carry, and I want you automatically in the second quantities of the product that can be loaded.

Examples:
If you choose dishes , it can lead to a 6, 12 or 24 dishes. However , if you choose glasses , it can take one of a 5 or a 10. I'm working on Symfony2 and have an entity called Categories , which has 1 field ' category ' , and a ratio of 1 to many with another entity having the amounts by which the products of that category ( of 6 , 12, 24 ) are sold . and then I have a relationship of one to many with the entity 'Products' where all the products in each category .
I'm told you do with AJAX, but nevertheless not how.

Comment: The general way. 1. get the chosen category using js 2. send it to the server using ajax (perhaps jquery) 3. get the response from the server with the number of dishes 4. display the number of dishes in your page or do whatever you want with it. (if you're using jquery's ajax you can do this using the `success` callback)

Comment: In addition previous comment, you can load all features on the page with JSON and change <select> with javascript.